# What is the risk of destroying working software by upgrading from natty narwhal to oneric ocelot?

Tags: 11.10, installation, 11.04, upgrade

I would like to know what happens with my good tuned system on natty narwhal when I upgrade to oneric-ocelot. I cannot find any threads in the forum which is very strange.

Thanks for your answers in advance

Ciao
Roberto

Comment: It depends on your hardware. Newer versions maybe more demanding of resources. It depends on your software requirements. If you rely on software that's no longer being supported, that maybe a problem for you. It's not possible to provide a definitive answer. You may get clues by trying out a live CD or USB and by asking more a specific question and by sharing your hardware specs and software needs.

Comment: Possibly by same poster here: http://ubuntuforums.org/newreply.php?do=newreply&noquote=1&p=12388718

Answer (score 1):

1. I wouldn't suggest to stay on 11.10: After upgrading to oneiric ocelot, you should be aware that support (security updates) for 11.10 will be ended in April 2013. You could upgrade to 12.04 after that and have support until 2017: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
2. If you use gnome desktop 2.x, you should consider installing `gnome-session-fallback` (which is a gnome 2.x look-alike and you can select it upon logging in). You could also try out other desktop managers like [cinnamon desktop](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) [from a ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable).
3. When you upgrade, the system disables any third party repositories, even launchpad PPA archives. You can always re-enable them.
4. Before trying upgrade you should **backup** your data (and/or partitions to another disk), at least the important stuff, so that in the small chance of something going wrong you have them stored in a safe place.
5. As a personal note, always keep your changes in a text file, e.g. "I installed these packages: (names of packages)" or "I use this ppa for this reason (link to ppa)" or "I changed file (path to file) to be like this (paste the contents of the file". This way you always know what you changed and you can format the root partition of ubuntu and re-apply your changes.